# Negative lookahead of an odd number `\` before the requested letter

Tags: c#, regex

How can one find all the letters `a` of a string but with the condition that the there is no odd number of `\` directly in front of it.

To do with one `\` would be

```
@"(?<!\\)a"
```

which works quiet well. But how to get all odd numbers of `\` be excluded?

For instance

- `a`, `\\a`, `\\\\a`, ... should be allowed
- `\a`, `\\\a`, `\\\\\a`, ... should be neglected

PS. It would be nice if the C# class `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` could handle your result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*a
```

See [DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%5C%5C)(%5C%5C%5C%5C)*a&i=a%2C%20%5C%5Ca%2C%20%5C%5C%5C%5Ca%0D%0A%5Ca%2C%20%5C%5C%5Ca%2C%20%5C%5C%5C%5C%5Ca)

Explanation:

- `(?<!\\)` lookbehind for no `\` (to avoid matching `\`'s from between)
- `(?:\\\\)*` match zero or more of double slashes `\\` (escaped by `\` each..) to match only even number of `\`'s
- `a` match literal `a`